# Find first hash key with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def job_ids
 {
   job_id:   r.job_id,
   job_2_id: r.job_2_id,
   job_3_id: r.job_3_id
 }
end

def available_job_id
   job_ids.find { |_k, v| v.nil? }[0].to_s
end
```

im checking which key has the first value of `nil`,and then i convert it to string.

what's the best way to do it?

This seems to be dirty?

`job_ids.find { |_k, v| v.nil? }[0].to_s`

UPDATE:
here's the desired output so far...

```
[79] pry(main)> job_ids.find{|k, v| v.nil?}[0].to_s
=> "job_2_id"
```

Comment: What do you want to convert into string? `nil` value? Please show us a desired output.

Comment: the key name @mudasobwa. see my updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
job_ids.key(nil).to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`key`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key)

```
job_ids.key(nil).to_s
#=> "job_2_id"
```